# What are the programming skills need for android kernel development?

Tags: android, kernel

I am an android application developer and i need to know that what are the programming skills needed to develop an android kernel. I mean to know that what are the programming language and knowledge need for that.

Answer (score 3):

The Android kernel is simply a Linux kernel, so the skills needed are the same as for that: you need to know C, be confident with low-level programming making heavy use of pointers (probably including pointers to functions, which are used heavily by the linux kernel), and be familiar with issues of programming directly on hardware (memory mapped device access, virtual/physical address mapping, etc.).